# R calculate overlapping months between two start and end dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with two start and stop dates that looks like this:

```
ID    G1_START    G1_END    G2_START    G2_END    LOCATION
1     1/1/2021   5/31/2021   2/1/2021   5/31/2021    A
2     12/1/2020  3/31/2021   10/1/2020  5/31/2021    B
```

What I would like to do is create one row per month per patient where the months overlap between the four dates. For example

```
ID    MONTH    ACTIVE    LOCATION
1    2/1/2021    1          A
1    3/1/2021    1          A
1    4/1/2021    1          A
1    5/1/2021    1          A
2    12/1/2020   1          B
2    1/1/2021    1          B
2    2/1/2021    1          B
2    3/1/2021    1          B
```

Where active means the ID was on **both** G1 and G2 during these months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method in [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Reshape data from wide to long format - [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)
2. Convert the date columns 'START', 'END' to `Date` class (`mdy`)
3. Loop over the 'START', 'END' with `map2`, get the sequence by '1 month'
4. Floor the date by month - [`floor_date`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.3.3/topics/floor_date)
5. grouped by ID, LOCATION, MONTH, `filter` the groups where 'Categ' distinct elements are 2
6. Create 'ACTIVE' column of 1 after returning the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = contains("_"),
       names_to = c("Categ", ".value"), names_sep= "_") %>%     
    transmute(ID, LOCATION, Categ, MONTH = map2(mdy(START), mdy(END), ~ 
       floor_date(seq(.x, .y, by = '1 month'), 'month'))) %>% 
    unnest(MONTH) %>%
    group_by(ID, LOCATION, MONTH) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(Categ) == 2) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    distinct(ID, LOCATION, MONTH) %>%
    mutate(ACTIVE = 1) %>%
    select(ID, MONTH, ACTIVE, LOCATION)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     ID MONTH      ACTIVE LOCATION
  <int> <date>      <dbl> <chr>   
1     1 2021-02-01      1 A       
2     1 2021-03-01      1 A       
3     1 2021-04-01      1 A       
4     1 2021-05-01      1 A       
5     2 2020-12-01      1 B       
6     2 2021-01-01      1 B       
7     2 2021-02-01      1 B       
8     2 2021-03-01      1 B
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, G1_START = c("1/1/2021", "12/1/2020"
), G1_END = c("5/31/2021", "3/31/2021"), G2_START = c("2/1/2021", 
"10/1/2020"), G2_END = c("5/31/2021", "5/31/2021"), LOCATION = c("A", 
"B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```